# Recover lost Umbraco Forms files from App_Plugins

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-contour, umbraco-forms

Suddenly the files inside the folder `App_Plugins/UmbracoForms` have vanished and I cannot seem to recover them. The files include `UmbracoForms.config`, `version`, `installed` as well as the most important form data inside the `Data` folder.

Checking the file/folder history it seems that the files were last modified by the Application Pool user identity, meaning the website deleted it's own files.

Why would this happen and how is it possible to recover these files?

Comment: What version of Umbraco Forms is the site running?

Comment: Umbraco Forms version 4.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across Forms/Umbraco deleting anything out of the App_Plugins folder without a user uninstalling the plugin in the back office.

Is it possible that someone has done a publish via VS or similar that's cleared the folder and replaced it?

In terms of getting the files back, if they've been deleted, you should in theory be able to recover them from your hosting company's back-ups (assuming the site is being regularly backed up).

Comment: Yes at the moment we are looking at restoring the file system backups; however it feels like a very fragile implementation. There had been a deployment through "Publish to File" but the `App_Plugins` folder is excluded. Also the file version history clearly indicates the file was modified by the website's app pool user identity.